What is the relationship between determinantal varieties?
Let $X$ be an $m\times n$ matrix.For a given positive integer $t ≤ \min(m,n)$, we denote the determinantal ideal $I_t = I_t(X)$ generated by the t-minors.What is the relationship between $I_1,I_2,I_3,\cdots$?
Can I get $I_{3}$ through some operations on $I_2$?
I know that $V(I_2)$ is Segre variety and it can be seen as the product of two projective spaces.I hope that I can find "$?$" such that $I_2\ ?\  I_2 =I_3$.

Set $M_k:=V(I_k) \subset \operatorname{Mat}(m \times n) \simeq \mathbb{A}^{mn}$.
(1) If $k < \min\{m, \, n\}$ then  $M_{k-1}$ is precisely the singular locus of $M_k$. See
E. Arbarello, M. Cornalba, P. A. Griffiths, J. Harris: Geometry of Algebraic Curves, p. 69.
(2) The determinantal variety $M_k$ is the $k$th secant variety to $M_1$, see MSE question 4384405.

Only for $k < \operatorname{min}(m,n)$.

Thanks for your answer. I know the result, but I don't understand how it can help me. I hope that smaller k can lead to larger k, but this seems to be the opposite.

Then you must consider secant varieties. I will add it in the answer.

@Sasha: fixed, thanks (it seems that [ACGH] forget to specify this, too...)

For the second statement you should put $M_2$ instead of $M_1$. In this notation $M_k$ are the matrices of rank $k-1$. $M_{k+1}$ is the $k$ secant variety of $M_2$. Other than that, aren't these statements true when $k=\min(m,n)$?

Sorry, please disregard that comment. I think it's better to simply put $M_k=V(I_{k+1})$, then everything is fine.
